# PHP How to add to an array at any index?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

Hello I just started learning PHP about 8 days ago.  I am trying to load comments form an SQL table and put them in order by their ID.  To do this I want to use an array and add to the index that the comment id is then it would be in order.

EX: (Ik this is not proper code)

```
while loop through SQL table{
   array[3] = This is comment 3.
   array[1] = This is comment 1.
   array[0] = This is comment 0.
   array[2] = This is comment 2.
}
```

As you can see it puts the comments in correct order just by their index.  How would I do this in PHP?

Here is what I have so far and it does NOT work:

```
$return = "";
    $array = array();
    $lowers = 0;


    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from `".Mod::$id."_comments`");
    if($res2){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
            if($row['id'] < $lowers){
                $lowers = $row['id'];
            }
            $name = $row['id'] . "_delete";
            $array[$row['id']] = "<div class=\"caption\"><hr><h5>"
            . getUserByUUID($row['uuid']) . " (" .  date('m/d/Y', $row['timestamp']) . ") <input type=\"button\" name=\"" . $name .
            "\" id=\"" . $name . "\" value=\"Delete\" onClick=\"CALLJAVASCRIPTFUNCTIONHERE()\" ></h5>
                    <figure class=\"img-polaroid\">" . 
                    $row['comment'] . "</figure>
                </div>";//TODO CHANGE THE CALL JAVA SCRIPT FUNCTION TO THE PROPER FUNCTION!!!!!
            alert("ARRAY: " . $array[$row['id']]);//This is getting called but it does nothing.  Also I made a php function called alert that DOES work.
        }
    }



    for($loop = $lowers; $loop < (count($array) + $lowers); $loop++){
        alert("LOOP: " . $loop);
        $return = $return + $array[$loop];
    }

    return $return;

    for($loop = $lowers; $loop < (count($array) + $lowers); $loop++){
        alert("LOOP: " . $loop);
        $return = $return + $array[$loop];
    }

    return $return;
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: why you want to use array for this this can be done by simple query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to sort the PHP array by index (key), then what you're looking for is a built in function called [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

From PHP.net (the link above): *Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is useful mainly for associative arrays.*

---

If you're looking to sort the returned ID's from the database, just change your query to:

```
"SELECT * from `".Mod::$id."_comments` ORDER BY `id` ASC" (DESC if you want the newest first)
```

Answer (score 1):

Buddy your approach is totally wrong. Why looping and processing unnecessarily?

You could do that at the time of executing query by using ORDER BY Clause.

Answer (score 0):

**You dont need that whole code**, remove that and try the code in this answer , 
and change the value where you have to, 
dont forget to change **YourTableName** to your **actual table name**.
what it gonna do its going to select every thing and will order result by their id. Thanks,

```
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from YourTableName ORDER BY id ASC");
//Change YourTableName to your actual table name
  if($res2){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){

            echo $row['id'].'  :'.$row['comment'].'<br/>';

        }
        }
```